# Perl function string2hex

Tags: perl

I have a function:

```
sub ascii_to_hex ($)
{
    ## Convert each ASCII character to a two-digit hex number.
    (my $str = shift) =~ s/(.|\n)/sprintf("%02lx", ord .$1)/eg;
    return $str;
}
```

I need to add a '%' before each number. To receive %68%75%44

Comment: You almost certainly don't want that function prototype.

Comment: Is it a typo that you wrote `ord . $1` (note the period inbetween) as your sprintf argument? Because that will use `$_` for `ord`, and then try to concatenate it with `$1`.

Comment: `s/(.|\n)//` would be better as `s/.//s`

Answer (score 11):

`%%` is used in `sprintf` format string to print a percent sign.

Comment: good explanation about `sprintf` [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)

Answer (score 3):

CPAN solution:

```
use URI::Escape;
sub ascii_to_hex { return uri_escape(shift, "\x00-\xFF"); }
```

Or

```
use URI::Escape qw(%escapes);
sub ascii_to_hex {
    (my $str = shift) =~ s/[\s\S]/$escapes{$1}/g;
    return $str;
}
```

URI::Escape is part of the URI package, which while not Core, it is required by many other modules and does tend to be installed on most systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub ascii_to_hex ($)
{
  return join("", map { '%'.sprintf("%02x", ord($_)) } split(//, shift));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape the `%` by doubling it.

```
( my $str = shift ) =~ s/(.)/ sprintf "%%%02x", ord $1 /seg;
return $str;
```

But this is surely a bit faster:

```
( my $str = unpack 'H*', shift ) =~ s/(..)/%$1/sg;
return $str;
```

By the way, since 5.14, you can do

```
return unpack('H*', shift) =~ s/(..)/%$1/sgr;
```